# Why Does the MVC ViewEngine not Iterate Through This Array of MvcHtmlStrings?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have the following in an EditorTemplate`:

```
@{
    var items = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem
        { Text = "one", Value = "one" },
        new SelectListItem
        { Text = "two", Value = "two" },
        new SelectListItem
        { Text = "3", Value = "3" },
    };
}

@Html.DropDownList("somename", items)
@Html.RadioButtonList("somename", items)
```

The `@Html.DropDownList` returns a dropdownlist just like I expect, but the `@Html.RadioButtonList` just returns the following *text*:

```
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString[]
```

The `@Html.RadioButtonList` extension method is from the `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Futures` nuget package, and the method signature is

```
public static MvcHtmlString[] RadioButtonList(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
  string name, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList)
```

Whereas the signature for DropDownList extension method is:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownList(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
  string name, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList)
```

It seems to me that the view engine is taking the `MvcHtmlString` returned from `DropDownList` and calling `ToString()` on that - which works just fine - but when it calls `ToString()` on the `MvcHtmlString` *array* returned from `RadioButtonList` it's returning exactly what I'd expect - a `ToString()` call on an array just returns the type name as a string.

It looks like the `Futures` people expected the view engine to iterate through the contents of the `MvcHtmlString[]` rather than just call `ToString()`.

Now my question is "How can I fix this - can I customize the view engine to iterate through this array like (I assume) they expected?"

Comment: I'm not seeing where the extension method `RadioButtonList` is even defined, it doesn't show up in my VS or documentation.  Is it custom?

Comment: It's from the `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Futures` nuget package - your question helped a lot in my investigation; I've added additional context to my post.

Comment: Hmm... Customizing the view engine might be a bit drastic.  I wonder if the simplest approach would be to just loop over the result and emit each member of the collection.  Could even be something as simple as a call to `string.Join`, or even abstracted behind a custom helper method.  I haven't used that Futures library, but I also don't see any other helpers that I can access which return an array.

Comment: Yeah, but there are other methods in the library that return an array - I would think the ViewEngine would be smarter than this.

Comment: One might hope, but... "last updated 12/6/2013".  Sounds like this is an old one-off library which still contains some stuff that was never approved for or incorporated into the main product.  Mileage may vary.

Comment: ... I wonder how hard it would be to write an ActionFilter that would concatenate `MvcHtmlString[]` into a single `MvcHtmlString` ... hmm...